# Php wont input data into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli, xampp

So im trying to get my data from my form submission to be put into a mysql database but whenever i submit a form it gives me this error: Error: INSERT INTO `form_submissions`(`ID`, `first`, `last`, `phone`, `class`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5])

Now here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "form_database";

$value = $_POST['first'];
$value1 = $_POST['last'];
$value2 = $_POST['phone'];
$value3 = $_POST['class'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error){
die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

$sql = "INSERT INTO `form_submissions`(`ID`, `first`, `last`, `phone`,
`class`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5])";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Submitted Successfully";
} else {``
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Use quotes, not brackets, as your string delimiters

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: what you have there `[value-x]` is mssql/oracle syntax, not mysql

Comment: and make sure that you have the right privileges to do that operation, after seeing this comment from you [*"Table 'form_submissions' is read only"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961285/php-wont-input-data-into-database#comment73017240_42961366) - You are reading comments here, right?

Comment: I guess you're not.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that ID is auto-incrementing, and that the others are text,

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `form_submissions`(`first`, `last`, `phone`,
 `class`) VALUES ('$value','$value1','$value2','$value3')";
```

Comment: ID is auto-incrementing and others are text yes, changed to that but still prompts me with error: Error: INSERT INTO `form_submissions`(`first`, `last`, `phone`,`class`) VALUES ('Anna','brown','07666435756','Big band sound')
Table 'form_submissions' is read only

Answer (score 0):

**Your query should be like:**

```
INSERT INTO `form_submissions`(`first`, `last`, `phone`, `class`) 
VALUES ('John','doe', '98564', 'SOMECLASS');
```

**To check:** echo the $sql query and debug it in phpmyadmin. 
**Note:** If you enabled AUTO_INCREMENT, you can ignore the data feed of that column. It will do its job automatic.

Security tip - > 
To prevent SQLi Injection check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: [Escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score -2):

There are two things wrong.

The first thing is you give 5 fields (ID, First, last, phone, class)
And you only have 4 variables in your post. I think you don’t need to send the ID on an insert if the column is set to auto increment in the database, So don’t send an value for the ID field.

Your variables are not correctly inserted in the query.
The [value-1] douse not mean the $value1 variable will automatically be injected in there.
This can be done in a lot of way’s 
I wil give you a simple solution, (but it wil be a bad one for real websites). The simple solution is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `form_submissions`(`first`, `last`, `phone`,`class`) VALUES (`$value`,`$value1`,`$value2`, `$value3`)";
```

The reason this is bad is: You are directly entering post data inside your query and are now vounerable to SQL-Injections. You need to escape your post data befoure inserting it in a query. Or better yet don’t use ‘mysqli’ but an PDO.
An good PDO example can be found here
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

I hope this helps.

Comment: Done this and prompted with error: Error: INSERT INTO form_submissions(first, last, phone, class) VALUES (‘”.Anna.”’,‘”.brown.”’,‘”.07666435756.”’, ‘”.Big band sound.”’)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '��”.Anna.”’,‘”.brown.”’,‘�' at line 1

Comment: Something is going wrong with the quotes. So I will try to fix that, you will se an eddit shortly

Comment: Becouse my spelling is so bad, i use word to correct my spelling befoure I past it here. But word changes the single quotes to other simbols. I removed the double quotes and changed the single quotes to the correct ones

Answer (score -3):

Your SQL is apparently wrong. It should look's like with something like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `form_submissions`(`ID`, `first`, `last`, `phone`,
`class`) VALUES ($value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5)";
```

The field ID should be auto_increment. If it is, you don't need to pass value to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql